# How to do chown 1000:1000 on the elasticsearch data directory in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm getting the `Failed to created node environment` error with an elasticsearch docker image:

```
[unknown] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
```

The persistent volume for elasticsearch data is at `/mnt/volume/elasticsearch-data`.

I'm able to solve this problem by `ssh` into the remote machine and run `chown 1000:1000 /mnt/volume/elasticsearch-data`. But I don't want to do it manually. How can I solve this privilege issue using the `deployment.yaml` file?

I've read that using `fsGroup: 1000` in `securityContext` should solve the problem, but it isn't working for me.

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: me-name/elasticsearch:6.7
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: elasticsearch-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: elasticsearch-volume
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
        capabilities:
          add:
            - IPC_LOCK
            - SYS_RESOURCE
      volumes:
        - name: elasticsearch-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elasticsearch-pv-claim
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144"]
```

storage.yaml:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/volume/elasticsearch-data"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be on [open bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1990) regarding permissions hostPath volumes. To work around this issue you should create an initContainer initially setting the proper permissions:

```
piVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: set-permissions
          image: registry.hub.docker.com/library/busybox:latest
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/data && chown 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data' ]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: elasticsearch-volume
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: me-name/elasticsearch:6.7
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: elasticsearch-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: elasticsearch-volume
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
        capabilities:
          add:
            - IPC_LOCK
            - SYS_RESOURCE
      volumes:
        - name: elasticsearch-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elasticsearch-pv-claim
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144"]
```

<del>You are on the right track by setting the `fsGroup` but what you are currently doing is setting the *user* to `1000` and mounting the volume with access to the *group* `1000`. What you should change is to use `runAsGroup: 1000` instead of `runAsUser: 1000`.</del>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it doesn't work. The folder at /mnt/volume/elasticsearch-data is still  owned by root instead of `1000`.  The output of  `ls -l command`:  `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 elasticsearch-data`

Comment: @RedGiant Did you remove the volume before you tried the change?

Comment: Yes, I've removed the volume. I also ssh into the machine and deleted `/mnt/volume/elasticsearch-data` before trying the change.

Comment: thank you! The new solution works. The only thing I need to change is the opening quotation mark in the command: `mkdir -p....`, which doesn't match the one at the end.

Comment: Great. No clue how that quotation mark got there but it's now fixed